# How to use xpath in selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am new to Selenium Python. I am trying to run the following snippet. It works with find_element_by_name but not find_element_by_xpath.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

```
from selenium import webdriver
# create a new Firefox session
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.maximize_window()
# navigate to the application home page
driver.get("https://www.google.co.uk/")
# get the search textbox

#search_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//@name='q'/")  <<<<< NOT Working
search_field = driver.find_element_by_name("q")

search_field.clear()
# enter search keyword and submit
search_field.send_keys("phones")
search_field.submit()
```

Comment: If the solution below is correct and works for you, then mark as correct , please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this
search_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='q']")

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You are using

## search_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//@name='q'/")

which is not correct syntax for xpath
The correct syntax for xpath should be -> \\tag_name[@attribute_name="attribute_value"]

For above example it should be
\input[@name='q']

try this one

```
search = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name="q"]')
```